# Percentage increase of two percentages

Tags: percentages

Can anyone help me with this problem?  What is the percentage increase from 27.7% to 28.2%?  I came up with 1.8% but my brother keeps telling me it's 18%

Comment: $18\%$ is more than a sixth. $27/6=4.5$ so you should see an increase of at least 4.5 units, which you don't

Answer (score 2):

$$\frac{28.2}{27.7}\approx1,018$$

So the answer is $100(1.018-1)=1.8$%